# Automated spaceship layout - do algorithms to compact cuboids exist?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, computational-geometry

I'm working on an algorithm to automate a plausible spaceship layout. As input, I have a list of modules (reactor, crew quarters, sensors, railguns, etc.) and for each module the following:

- int length, width and height
- floating point preference center/hull
- int strength of preference
- floating point preference front/back
- int strength of preference

For example, the crew quarters should be in the center to shield them from cosmic rays, the thrusters and radiators must be on the outside, as well as sensors or solar cells.

Let's assume that all modules are cuboids, do not overlap and have otherwise no interactions. Does an algorithm exist do automatically layout a list of cuboids in three dimensions so the preferences are matched as good as possible?
In addition to matching the preferences, the maximum distance between any module and the center of mass should be minimized to increase stability and make turning easier.

A naive solution would be to sort the modules by their center/hull preference, start with the centermost module and slap on the others where they fit, in increasing order of hull-preference. However, this would probably leave large holes and give no guarantees.

Comment: This is more difficult than packing cuboids in 3D space (without preference information), which is more difficult than packing rectangles in a plane region, which is already a difficult problem.  Your best bet is probably to decide on a quality function that only gets worse as new pieces are added; then you can apply branch-and-bound search.  If that's too slow, you can use beam search for an approximate solution.

Comment: Thanks for the classification related to other problems and the suggestion. I'll have a look at more general algorithms.